How to optimize excel writing using SXSSFWorkbook？
I wrote 100,000 pieces of data in a loop. Why did I download more than 60,000 excel files at last? The last file is also.XSLS, and the last file I downloaded is 33MB. Thanks for reply

Why are there more than 60,000 excel files downloaded at last?
Why does the memory occupy 3GB? Is there any optimization method?
Thanks for reply.


It sounds like you’re generating many Excel files (60,000+) while working with a large dataset (100,000 pieces). There are a few possible reasons why you encountered this issue; therefore, can you add more details to the questions?
